# Notation: limit in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, continuity

> I want to show that the function
>   $$
> f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \
> (x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases}
> x^2(x-1)(y-1)\sin(xy), & (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   is continuous.

Obviously, both pieces are continuous because they are composed of elementary continuous functions.
Now I only need to show that the transition between both pieces is continuous and don't know how to notate it properly. My Idea was
\begin{align*}
            \lim_{\|x,y\|_{\infty} \nearrow 1} f|_{[0,1]}
            & = \lim_{\max(x,y) \nearrow 1}  x^2(x - 1)(y - 1)\sin(xy) \\
            & = \begin{cases}
            \lim_{x \nearrow 1}  x^2(x - 1)(y - 1)\sin(xy) \\
            \lim_{y \nearrow 1}  x^2(x - 1)(y - 1)\sin(xy)
            \end{cases}
            = \begin{cases} 1^2(1 - 1)(y - 1)\sin(y) \\ x^2(x - 1)(1 - 1)\sin(x) \end{cases}
            = 0
        \end{align*}
I've never seen it done that way but didn't have a better idea.

**Second Attempt**
For all $a \in [0,1]$ we have
        \begin{equation*}   
    \begin{cases}
        \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,a)} f(x,y)
        = 0^2(0 - 1)(a - 1)\sin(0)
        = 0
        = f(0,a), \\
        \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(1,a)} f(x,y)
        = 1^2(1 - 1)(a - 1)\sin(y)
        = 0
        = f(1,a). \\
        \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(a,0)} f(x,y)
        = a^2(a - 1)(0 - 1)\sin(0)
        = 0
        = f(a,0), \\
        \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(a,1)} f(x,1)
        = a^2(a - 1)(1 - 1)\sin(x)
        = 0
        = f(a,1) 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove continuity we need to show that for $0\le a\le 1$

- $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,a)}f(x,y)=f(0,a)=0$
- $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,a)}f(x,y)=f(1,a)=0$
- $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,0)}f(x,y)=f(a,0)=0$
- $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,1)}f(x,y)=f(a,1)=0$

Comment: The variables $x, y$ in an expression of the form $\lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)}f(x, y)$ are bound to their occurrences in $f(x, y)$. You cannot simultaneously use them as free variables occurring in $(a, b)$.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Ok that’s a good point! I fix that, thanks.

Comment: So my reasoning for the first would be $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,a)} f(x,y) = 0^2(0 - 1)(a - 1)\sin(0) = 0 = f(0,a)$$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik For the first for we have $|x^2(x-1)(y-1)\sin(xy) \to 0\cdot (-1) \cdot (a-1)\cdot \sin (0\cdot a)=0$.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I wrote, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, in that case the check is indeed pretty trivial!

Comment: All others are similarly easy, right? Or did I overlook something? I will post my 'calculations' into the answer.

Comment: Yes that’s correct!